# Tax returns in 2 states

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax

I live in MA, but did an internship in CA in 2016. Filed electronically the tax returns for IRS and 2 states, applying the CA tax amount as a credit in the MA return, as it is usually done. However, while Fed and CA went fine, the MA dep. of revenue still can't process my return, because they don't see where did this credit came from.

My understanding is that the electronic tax prep systems automatically send all the forms and returns everywhere they belong, and the user has little control of it. How is it possible then that MA does not know about my CA tax? If I file an MA amendment (with the same numbers), how do I make sure that the information about my CA tax is also sent along? All my tax forms are already in the tax prep system, so I have nothing extra to add.

Answer (score 1):

Electronic tax prep systems do their best but it's really easy for there to be user error, errors at the departments of revenue, or bugs in the software.  State governments are not as automated or bug-free as we would like and there are too many possibilities for us to know what went wrong.

These types of tax prep systems typically allow you to print out the return as filed.  Print it out and take a look.  If it's not obvious what went wrong, contact the Massachusetts dept of revenue and ask what the problem is. You can do it through your account at [MassTaxConnect](https://mtc.dor.state.ma.us/mtc/_/#1) or they will have included a phone number for you to call in whatever correspondence you have.  The person you talk to will be able to tell you what they are missing and how to rectify the situation.

No one likes talking to the tax man, but in this case that's the only person who can help you.  Helping resolve this type of problem is in the job description of the person who will receive your message or phone call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I already did all these, and I manually checked the numbers and know the return is correct, and the guy from MA DOR said "there's an error but i don't know where", "yeah, it might be that other state credit", "yeah, you probably can file an amendment", so he doesn't know what they need exactly.

Comment: Dang government employees.  If you try again you might get someone more competent.  Good luck.